# not able to set POST parameter in PHP api

Tags: php, json, api, rest, advanced-rest-client

I am building an android app with api coded in PHP. I am trying to send POST values from my app, but none of the values are being set. I also tried with other REST client apps with setting appropriate parameters, but it is neither working for them too. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
//an array to display response
$response = array();
if(isset($_POST['dbname']) && isset($_POST['class']) && isset($_POST['rollno']) && isset($_POST['password'])&& isset($_POST['firebase_id'])){
    $pos_dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];
    $rollno = $_POST['rollno'];
    $pos_password = $_POST['password'];
    $firebase_id = $_POST['firebase_id'];
    //further logic goes on...
    ...
    ...
} else{
    $response['dbname'] = isset($_REQUEST['dbname']);
    $response['class'] = isset($_POST['class']);
    $response['rollno'] = isset($_POST['rollno']);
    $response['password'] = isset($_POST['password']);
    $response['firebase_id'] = isset($_POST['firebase_id']);
    $response['message'] = "Insufficient Parameters";    
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I am getting response

```
{"dbname":false,"class":false,"rollno":false,"password":false,"firebase_id":false,"message":"Insufficient Parameters"}
```

Tried with PHP versions 5, 7.0 and 7.1 but I really can't understand why it is not taking up the POST parameters. Its working for GET parameters. Also, it is not working in local as well as remote environment.
Here i m putting a screenshot of my request in one of the REST client app
[image]

Comment: Kindly post the client client code too

Comment: @MuhibAhmed I have posted a screenshot of the REST client app with parameters.

Comment: What are you using to POST?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I am using [ARC](https://install.advancedrestclient.com/install) rest client to test this api

Comment: well the code looks fine.. the problem seems to be your client app.. try using any different app like postman or cURL..

Comment: If I may suggest checking the content type header in the "Headers" tab. If it's not set to "application/x-www-urlencoded" then the request won't be properly understood by the server. @AshishJoshi

Comment: @PawelPsztyc Yes, the header tab is set to "application/x-www-urlencoded". It is visible in the screenshot above.

Comment: @AshishJoshi sorry for the late response. This is not the same as the header value (sadly). It only tells you what type of editor is currently rendered. It should replace the header value but sometimes it doesn't.